# Issue whith display:table-cell on Firefox (21, OSX)

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm having issues with a DIV container displaying DIVs in table-cell mode with Firefox 21, OS X (10.8 Mountain Lion).

It works perfectly on Chrome / Safari.

You can actually view my webpage here: http://staging-new-hp.videonot.es
Look for the `#works-with` div and its children.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved this issue following 3rror404's answer and adding some stuff like `width:100%` on each container and `table-layout:fixed`. Works both on Webkit (Chrome, Safari) and Firefox.

Here's the full CSS (SCSS syntax):

```
#works-with {
    width: 100%;

    .container-box {
      width: 100%;
      display: table;
      table-layout: fixed;

      .platforms {
        width: 100%;
        display: table-row;

        .platform {
          display: table-cell;
          vertical-align: middle;
          text-align: center;
          width: 17%;
          margin-right: 15px;
          margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
      }
    }
```

And the corresponding HTML:

```
<section id="works-with">
            <h2>Works with</h2>

            <div class="container-box">
                <div class="platforms">
                    <div class="platform">
                        <img .../>
                    </div>

                    <div class="platform">
                        <img .../>
                    </div>

                    <div class="platform">
                        <img ./>
                    </div>

                    <div class="platform">
                        <img .../>
                    </div>

                    <div class="platform">
                        <img .../>
                    </div>

                    <div class="platform">
                        <img .../>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the ancestors the correct `display` properties

```
#works-with {
    display: table;
}

#works-with .logos {
    display: table-row;
}

#works-with .logos .platform {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

`display: table-cell`is designed to mimic a HTML table cell. You wouldn't randomly place a `<td></td>` in the middle of your content without the correct table structure. Neither should you place a `display:table-cell` element without the correct structure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sounds logic, but it doesn't change anything actually the div is expanding over the 940px container DIV and displaying elements in big size.